# Distributional assumptions in Maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) and least squares estimator (LSE)

Tags: least-squares, maximum-likelihood

Many textbooks do mention that MLE does need some distributional assumptions but I could never find which they are. LSE on the opposite, doesn't need distributional assumptions but when missing certain distributional properties, the estimator will possibly not have nice  estimator properties. Which these are isn't mentioned either. Therefore my questions:

1) Which distributional assumptions does the MLE have?

2) Given which properties does the LSE have which favourable properties?

Comment: Do you refer to estimators for the coefficients of a linear regression model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the basic linear model
$$Y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1X_{1,t}+\cdots+\beta_kX_{k,t}+u_t,$$
where $X_{i,t}$ values are fixed (that is, not randomly determined but selected before measuring the $Y_t$ values), $u_t$ are random variables with a certain probability distribution.

That LSE don't need to specify a distribution for $u_t$ is evident since LSE are defined to be the values
$$\hat \beta_0,\ldots,\hat \beta_k$$
such that the function
$$S(\hat \beta_0,\ldots,\hat \beta_k)=\sum_{t=1}^T(Y_t-\hat\beta_0-\hat\beta_1X_{1,t}-\cdots-\hat\beta_kX_{k,t})^2$$
reaches its minimum value, and these values do not depend on the distribution of the $u_t$ variables.

On the other hand, the MLE are defined as the values
$$\hat \beta_0,\ldots,\hat \beta_k$$
such that the likelihood function
$$L(\hat \beta_0,\ldots,\hat \beta_k)=\prod_{t=1}^T f(u_t)=$$$$=\prod_{t=1}^T f(Y_t-\hat\beta_0-\hat\beta_1X_{1,t}-\cdots-\hat\beta_kX_{k,t})$$
reaches a maximum. But here, $f$ is the probability density function of the $u_t$ variables, so assuming a certain distribution for those $u_t$ random variables is an unavoidable first step for maximum likelihood estimation.

More precisely: there is not one set of MLE for the linear model, but actually one for each specific distribution assumption. And while from one case to another the properties of those different estimates will vary, for most cases there are some basic properties like consistency or asymptotic efficiency that will hold, since they're common to all MLE under quite general conditions.

On the other hand, there is just one set of LSE... but their properties will depend on the actual distribution of the $u_t$ r.v.

To summarize some known results, let's assume that (as was said at the beginning), the $X_{i,t}$ variables are not random. Then, if $\hat\beta_i$ are the LSE:

- if $E(u_t)=0,\;\forall t$, then $E(\hat\beta_i)=\beta_i$ (the LSE are unbiased);
- if —in addition—
  $$Var(u_t)=\sigma^2_u,\;\forall t$$
  (the same for all $t$, also known as the *homoskedasticity* assumption) and if
  $$cov(u_t,u_s)=0,\; t\neq s$$
  (*no autocorrelation* assumption) then the LSE have minimum variance among all linear unbiased estimators (BLUE);
- if also the distribution for $u_t$ is the normal distribution, then the LSE have minimum variance among ALL unbiased estimators, that is, they are *efficient* estimators (also known as MVUE or UMVUE).

Regarding the usual distributional assumption to perform MLE, actually it depends on the characteristics of the model; but in the simplest case it is quite usual to assume a normal distribution with zero mean, homoskedasticity and no autocorrelation, that is
$$u_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2_u),\; \forall t,\quad \wedge \quad cov(u_t,u_s)=0,\; t\neq s, $$
in which case the MLE for the $\beta_i$ parameters coincide with the LSE. Also, $\sigma^2_u$ can be estimated by maximum likelihood if unknown, and it's estimator turns out to be
$$\hat\sigma_u^2=\frac1n \sum_{t=1}^T \hat u_t,$$
where
$$\hat u_t=Y_t-\hat\beta_0-\hat\beta_1X_{1,t}-\cdots-\hat\beta_kX_{k,t}.$$

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! What I never fully understand is what is the difference between having lowest variance among all unbiased linear estimators and having lowest variance among all unbiased estimators? I.e., is the estimator itself somehow linear in the former case and in the latter non-linear? And can an estimator only be efficient if they re non-linear?

Comment: Let's see: the LSE is linear (in the $Y_1,\ldots,Y_T$ variables, which are the random variables you observe, since the $X$s are assumed to be fixed values). This can be seen for specific cases, or for the general matricial formula $\hat\beta=(X^tX)^{-1}X^tY$, which shows that $\hat \beta$ is a linear transformation of $Y$, since it is of the form $\hat\beta= A Y$.

Comment: If $\hat\beta$ is BLUE, this means that any other estimator of the form $\tilde \beta=AY+\vec b$ such that $E(\tilde \beta)=\beta$ has at least as much variance as the LSE. But it might be the case that another unbiased estimator which cannot be expressed as a linear transformation of $Y$ have lesser variance than the LSE.

Comment: On the other hand, when you know that the estimator is efficient, that can't happen (the LSE is still linear, since it is the same as before). 

By the way, note that it only makes sense to say that an estimator is BLUE if it is both linear and unbiased.

Comment: Again thanks a lot for your answers! I still do struggle a bit with the bit about the efficient estimators. As I have learned that it is the ratio of the standard error of the "optimal" estimator divided by the standard error of the estimator at hand. But I dont see why this defintion is restricted to non-linear estimators only, that is, why is a MVUE efficient but a BLUE not?

Comment: Ok, I guess I see the problem. It is not restricted to non-linear estimators. It considers all unbiased estimators, no matter if they are linear or non-linear. All them together, with no distinction.